# How to mock readline.createInterface()?

Tags: javascript, testing, jasmine, mocking, readline

I'm trying to write a test on jasmine to check that `readline.createInterface()` is called, but I keep getting an error that says: `TypeError: readline.createInterface is not a function`

Here's roughly what I have in a game class:

```
run() {
  let rl = readline.createInterface({
      input: process.stdin,
      output: process.stdout,
      prompt: 'OHAI> '
    });

  rl.prompt();
  // ... and the rest ... 
}
```

and my test:

```
describe('run', () => {
  it('should create readline interface', () => {
    let readline = jasmine.createSpyObj('readline', ['createInterface']);

    game.run();

    expect(readline.createInterface).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

Anyone has a suggestion?

Answer (score 5):

Try the following code (see above) and use [rewire](https://github.com/jhnns/rewire)

```js
const rewire = require('rewire')
const game = rewire('path/to/game')

describe('run', () => {
  it('should create readline interface', () => {
    const readline = jasmine.createSpyObj('readline', ['createInterface']);
    const revert = game.__set__('readline', readline);

    game.run();

    expect(readline.createInterface).toHaveBeenCalled();

    revert();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When I try to recreate this problem, I get a different error:

```
Expected spy readline.createInterface to have been called.
```

But if you're only spying on a single method, try jasmine's spyOn notation:

```
spyOn(readline, 'createInterface').and.callThrough();
```

With the same expectation. It's clearer than the jasmine.createSpyObj() notation for this use case, and doesn't use any additional libraries.

Source: https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html